# JointJS Manhattan Router not counting labels as obstacles. How to route link without overlapping labels?

Tags: javascript, jointjs

My application automatically routes some connection lines using [jointjs's manhattan router](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v2.0/joint.html#dia.Link.prototype.presentation). The issue I'm having is:

- the connection **lines are routed too close to other line's labels** (Manhattan router is **not considering labels from other lines as obstacles**)
- sometimes the connection **lines do not go down far enough for my text labels**

The file I believe I need to edit is:

https://github.com/clientIO/joint/blob/master/plugins/routers/joint.routers.manhattan.js

Please see these images to get a better idea of what I'm talking about:

***Before*** Manhattan Routing:

[image: before Manhattan routing]

***After*** Manhattan Routing:

[image: after Manhattan routing]

What my ***goal*** is:

[image: goal Manhattan routing]

I've tried using the other routers, but they were much worse for my specific application.

My configuration is as follows:

```
        link.set('router', {
            name: 'manhattan',
            args: {
                startDirections: ['bottom']
            }
        });
```

I've been looking at [joint.routers.manhattan.js](https://github.com/clientIO/joint/blob/master/plugins/routers/joint.routers.manhattan.js) but it's pretty complex...

Does anyone know what I can modify in [joint.routers.manhattan.js](http://[https://github.com/clientIO/joint/blob/master/plugins/routers/joint.routers.manhattan.js][5]) so that **labels are considered obstacles**?

Possible Solutions:

- Route with Manhattan first, then determine where to place label so that it is not conflicting with another label.
- Place labels first, then edit Manhattan so that labels are considered obstacles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few things I learned that helped me:

- Links are NOT elements. When you do `graph.getElements()`, the list will not include any links. Try running this in the javascript console:

  ```
      var map = graph.getElements()
      for(var m=0; m<map.length; m++)
      {
          console.log("Type: "+map[m].get('type')+", Bounding Box: "+map[m].getBBox());
      }
  ```
- Changing the `step` or `maximumLoops` options may help:

  ```
      link.set('router', {
          name: 'manhattan',
          args: {
              startDirections: ['bottom'],
              step: 10, 
              maximumLoops: 500
          }
      });
  ```
- One way to solve this issue is to **increase the `getBBox`** for elements where links are getting too close to.
- Another way to increase the size of the obstacle is to increase the manhattan router's `opt.paddingBox` variable. If you look at the source code, it is doing exactly what I need:

  ```
      // expand elements boxes by specific padding
      .invoke('moveAndExpand', opt.paddingBox)
  ```

I ended up adding extra padding to the manhattan file using the last suggestion listed above.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. In a similar issue, I actually defined events that [add vertices](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v2.0/joint.html#dia.LinkView.prototype.addVertex) in specific positions to each newly created link, this way there's less chance for them to end up in places you don't want. Btw, if you want to get elements and links, you can use [`graph.getCells()`](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v2.0/joint.html#dia.Graph.prototype.getCells).